# Access redux store inside Next.js API route

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I am trying to get access to my redux store but `useAppSelector` is a hook and it is not allowing me to use hooks.

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component.

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const { cartItems: cart } = useAppSelector((state) => state.cart)
      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items:
          [
          {
            // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
            price: 'price_1KCZvuJXbqMuWcYwIKesDoXE',
            quantity: 1,
          }, {
            // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
            price: 'price_1KCZvuJXbqMuWcYwIKesDoXE',
            quantity: 1,
          },
          ]
        ,
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      });
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

How can I access my cart without using a hook?

Comment: Where do you call handler(req, res) function ?

Comment: You can't - API routes run on the server while the Redux store lives on the client. You need to pass whatever values you need from the cart in your request to the API route.